# Circuit design for variable number of leds

Tags: led, resistance

I am very new to this field and turned onto it by adruino and raspberry pi. So for my next project I am looking to create, I wanna have 6 leds (20mA 3v) in a line. Now depending on my output from raspberry I want a certain of the 6 to be on at time and not the others and switch among them. I have a 12v battery that I want to power the circuit with. I am confused with what resistance and how should I connect them so as not to blow out the leds.

Comment: You *"wanna"*!?

Comment: so the ques really is that how do I handle the scenario when I can not be certain of the number of LEDs I have on at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ULN2003A to drive one LED per GPIO pin. Each LED gotta have a series resistor to +12V. 470 ohms will give almost 20mA.